# How do I comprehend the structure of this statement?

Tags: sentence-meaning, parsing

> The social obligations that scientists have as distinct from those responsibilities they share with all citizens comes from them having access to specialised knowledge of how the world works, not easily accessible to others. ([source](https://www.ielts-exam.net/docs/reading/IELTS_Reading_Academic_26_Passage_1.htm))

Answer (score 1):

All citizens share some responsibilities. Scientists have some additional social obligations. This is because they have access to specialized knowledge of how the world works. This information is not easily accessible to others.

I'm guessing the *as distinct from* tripped you up there, perhaps along with the rather meandering sentence structure.

Comment: Thanks a lot~

So the clause "as distinct from those responsibilities they share with all citizens" modified "obligations that scientists have" right? 

Since the clause ", not easily accessible to others." should mean "the knowledge is not easily accessible to others", 
the latter part of the clause should be "... knowledge of how the world works to which others are not easily accessible".
It it correct? 

thanks again.

Comment: and also the "them" in "comes from them" means the scientists right? So if saying "come from they", the "they" will be referring to the "obligations" right? thanks

Comment: "Come from they" is ungrammatical. I believe the general rule is that referential pronouns tie to the subject of the clause, which in this case is "the scientists".

Comment: Similarly your proposed *"knowledge of how the world works to which others are not easily accessible"* says "others" are "not accessible to" which is not correct here and grammatically uncanny. "Knowledge of how the world works which is not easily accessible to others" is how I would phrase that.

Comment: thank you very much

Comment: If this solved your problem, please consider accepting it. You can also post an answer of your own and accept that if you prefer. Marking an answer as accepted avoids having new people click open questions which no longer require additional attention. See also [help.](/help/someone-answers) Thanks in advance.